# Scroll WinRT ListView to particular group

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a ListView and grouped items inside of it. User has different ways of navigating into the page, and according to the way he navigates, I wish to have a certain group in view when the page opens.

I tried setting these:

```
itemGridView.ScrollIntoView(....);
itemGridView.SelectedIndex = ....;
itemGridView.SelectedItem = ....;
```

where itemGridView is the name of the ListView, but none of that seems to work.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some visual tree traversing to find the ScrollViewer that is part of the ListView template, find the group and scroll the ScrollViewer to the position of your group.

Comment: I'll give it a shot tomorrow. I was hoping for a simpler solution, but if a man has to traverse a visual tree, a man has to traverse a visual tree :D

Comment: WinRT XAML Toolkit should make it easy though. Just call var sv = itemGridView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>(), then var groupView = sv.GetDescendantsOfType<GroupViewType>().Where(gv => gv.DataContext == yourGroupViewModel), then sv.ScrollIntoView(gv). Well unless it does not work of course... :)

Comment: Where and when would it be safe to look for descendants if everything is data bound? I tried in Loaded event handler of the page, but it seems that not all the groups have been created yet (for example, the list of descendants has 3 items, even though I have 5 groups etc.)

Comment: It might have 3 items instead of 5 if it is using a virtualized panel. You might need to try doing something like this to disable virtualization, otherwise - I am not sure what the visual tree might be... <GridView.ItemsPanel><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" /></...

You could also try XAML Spy to analyze your visual tree and get a better understanding of what's in it.

Comment: Yap you were right, the stackpanel is virtualized and that's probably causing me troubles in traversing it.