# Let ListView scroll to selected item

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a WinRT/C#/XAML app with a view that has a vertical ListView of items. Depending on the amount of items the ListView shows a vertical scrollbar. Here's the XAML definition:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="myViewSource"
        Source="{Binding myViewModel.Items}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<ListView
    x:Name="myListView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewSource}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ListView>
```

Now everytime I navigate to this view, the selected item of the ListView is chosen by setting the databound SelectedItem property in the view model from code behind (`OnNavigatedTo`). My problem: the ListView doesn't scroll automatically to this selected item. The scrollbar remains at the top of the ListView and the user has to scroll manually to see the selected item.

I tried to execute `myListView.ScrollIntoView(MyViewModel.SelectedItem);` after setting the SelectedItem in the code behind (in `OnNavigatedTo`), but it doesn't work. The scrollbar remains at the top.

I'm aware of this thread on SO: [Scroll WinRT ListView to particular group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325384/scroll-winrt-listview-to-particular-group) .
This seems to be a similar problem. But when I walk the visual tree of the ListView manually or with the WinRT XAML Toolkit, it doesn't find a ScrollViewer (returns null instead).

Comment: Are you waiting for the ListView to load (be added to the visual tree) before you try scrolling?

Comment: I'm calling ScrollIntoView() in OnNavigatedTo(). I thought this would be the right place and the ListView should have been loaded. Or may I be wrong?

Comment: I think OnNavigatedTo occurs before the control is loaded...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to Filip I noticed that calling `ScrollIntoView()` in `OnNavigatedTo()` was too early, because the `ListView` control is not loaded yet in this place.

The first solution idea was to bind the `Loaded` event of the ListView:

```
myListView.Loaded += (s, e) => 
    myListView.ScrollIntoView(MyViewModel.SelectedItem);
```

Unfortunately that causes a nasty visual effect, where current ListView items overlap with the selected item for parts of a second, before everything is rearranged well.

The final solution I found is to call `ScrollIntoView()` asynchronously via the `Dispatcher` of the view:

```
myListView.Loaded += (s, e) => Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () => myListView.ScrollIntoView(MyViewModel.SelectedItem));
```

With this solution the layouting works fine.

Comment: I thing, that you have small syntax error in your solution - semicolon after this myListView.ScrollIntoView(MyViewModel.SelectedItem) lambda expression body.

Comment: In my case myListView.UpdateLayout() before myListView.ScrollIntoView() also helped

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need and resolved it in a slightly different manner.  I subscribed to the SelectionChangedEvent from the ListView and performed the scrolling within the handler.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" SelectionChanged="myListView_SelectionChanged" ...>
</ListView>
```

Code:

```
private void myListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.SelectedItem);
}
```